# Phone call programmatically in iOS using UIWebView without alertView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Is it possible to make a Phone call programmatically in iOS using UIWebView without alertView? Basically I know that when we subview a webview and hide it and try to call a number, It calls the number without any problem and gets back to application without any problem. The only thing is can we some how remove the alertview that appears when this webview executes the code "tel:"<phone number>. I also tried the openURL: method but after call finishes we don't get back to application. My requirement is I should make a call programmatically without interacting with any alert view and should get back to the application once we are done with the call.

Comment: this code will help to get back to the app after call ends but don't have idea about how to call without alert with webview try this : NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://123-4567-890"]; 
[[UIApplication  sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your requirement isn't possible to be implemented at the moment.

1. When you use a webview to make a call, you can't remove the alert as it is the UIWebView behaviour.
2. If you want, you can use the telprompt:// URL scheme. However, there is a risk that this URL scheme might get removed in future.

   ```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://%@",phoneNumber];
   if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url]) {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
   }
   ```

Again in this case, you will get the alert, but you will return back to the application.